# Is there a way to manually install modules for python?

Tags: python, module, installation

I keep running into problems with installing modules for python. Either because the modules themselves aren't able to be downloaded via pip or because of some error or another.

Is it possible to simply download the module as a .zip or tar.gz file (as I see a lot of links to do just that) and then somehow place them within the file that Python uses to store its modules (I think it's the Lib folder).

Is this possible? What are the pitfalls for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you can download a module's source (usually in the form of a `.tar.gz` archive) from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org). First, unpack the archive, then enter the folder that is created. Assuming that your Python binary is on your path, simply run

```
python setup.py install
```

or (for Python 3)

```
python3 setup.py install
```

and it will be built and installed. Of course, if the module contains extensions written in C/C++ that need to be compiled, you'll need to have a compiler installed and configured on your system, along with any requisite libraries.

If you're on Windows, you can find pre-compiled `.whl`s for many packages [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Details about all of this are easily available by googling.